# puts displays but %s does not

Tags: c, string, puts

My file has the following pattern.

> word1 word2 word3
>   wordzz word33 word2431 word341

and so on.

Now i read the whole file in an array of structure, each of the entry of the array maintains the linked list for each line of file.

Now the whole code is kind of difficult to explain, but here is the problem.

In a particular place when i try to do the following

```
printf("\n%s",ptr1->name);
puts(ptr1->name);
```

where `ptr1` is the ptr to the head of any linked list. (say line 1 )
name field is the name i.e. `word1,word2 etc.`
Now the output is

```
word1word1
word2word2
word3
```

Howcome `word3` does not get printed twice?
This whole problem even prevents me to `strcmp` the last word of the list.

Kindly help.

P.S.

also when i do

```
printf("%d",ptr1);
```

it prints three different values for `ptr`, none of them being `NULL`.

I have two similar arrays of the same structure. I use the same function to populate the two arrays. NOW

```
    node* ptr,*ptr1; 
ptr=first[i].ptr;
ptr1=second[i].ptr;
while(ptr!=NULL) 
{
printf(" \n1");
printf(" %s", ptr->name); // Works Fine
if(!strcmp(ptr->name,"string")) 
    {


    while(ptr1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("A %s ",ptr1->name);// Problem
                    fflush(stdout);  // EDITS AS ASKED BY USER `pmg`
                    puts(ptr1->name);       
                if(!strcmp(ptr1->name,strt))
        {
            printf("\n 4\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
        ptr1=ptr1->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;


    }
else 
    {
    ptr=ptr->next;
    }

}
```

Howcome i get problem @ the mentioned place, and not @ the 'works fine' place.

At works fine, i am shown all the nodes ( names ) but at the problem point i am not shown the last name.

But if i do puts at the problem , it displays that name too.

if before this snippet of code i print the second array using printf only. it does print every node (name) . 
Can someone tell me why is it not printing later.?

Comment: Based on your code, there's no reason why code that works for word2 would fail for word3. You probably omit something important.

Comment: you correctly spotted your problematic line: `printf("\n%s",ptr1->name);`. Putting the newline before the output string is just a bad habit. Always think of a line as being terminated by a '\n' and organize your code accordingly.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt That doesnt help much, maybe i dod not get what you were trying to say. But the problem for me is that `printf("%s",ptr->name);` would not print the last word for me.

Comment: Are you missing an assignment to `ptr1` (re-initializing for a new `prt`) inside the loop?

Comment: @pmg no the ptr1 would point to the same list as before the loop.
It does print two of the three, and just leaves out the last one, thoug puts prints all three. Also, i am not able to get right answer for strcmp since i want to compare with the last name of the list, but it wont give me the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("\n%s",ptr1->name); // Problem
```

`stdout` is line-buffered by default when connected to a terminal, you have to flush the stream to have the string printed. Use `fflush(stdout)` just after the `printf` call to flush `stdout`. Printing a new line character will also flush `stdout` when the stream is line-buffered.

`puts` does not need the additional new line character as `puts` always appends a new line character to the output.

As @JensGustedt mentioned in the question comment, putting the new line before the string is bad habit *"think of a line as being terminated by a '\n' and organize your code accordingly."*

Comment: no, it still wont work for me.
If i do `printf(" A %s",ptr1->name);` then all i get is the A (for the last one). though `puts` prints it correctly.

Comment: @Kraken did you write `printf(" A %s",ptr1->name); fflush(stdout);` as  in my answer?

Comment: if i write `printf("A %s ",ptr1->name);
            fflush(stdout);
            puts(ptr1->name);`  then i get the output `A otherModules otherModules
A DRIVERDEF DRIVERDEF
 ENDD` given that my three words were `otherModules` `DRIVERDEF` `END`

Comment: @Kraken: can you update the code in your question to include the (`fflush()`) and `puts()` call?

Comment: @ouah  if i put a few more spaces before %s  i get both `END` printed. What is really happening here, as i said, if before the code snippet i printf the whole of second array, i get no problem whatsoever, neither am i getting here too for otherModules and DRIVERDEF. Why Is `END` causing all the trouble.

Comment: AHA! Your `END` isn't 3 characters long. There is some control codes after the last `'D'`. Check it out.

Comment: @pmg edited. Also END infact is three char long, the additional D is the D of the second END. 
If i dont give any space after %s i get `ENDND` .

Comment: @ouah can you find out the mistake?

Comment: add `printf("--%d--", (int)strlen(ptr1->name));` somewhere near the problematic lines.